# C# How can i store Pivot data into List<T>

Tags: c#

I am calling a sql server store procedure which return pivot data now which i store in data table but i like to know how could i design my class as a result i can store Pivot format data in my List class.

here i am giving a screen shot which show what kind of data i am dealing with.
[image]

all the quarter data is not fixed. it is coming from database and it can be up-to any year. so please guide how to design my class as a result store the above data in my List class instead of data table.

if possible please explain this with a sample code and scenario.

thanks

Comment: Personally I would create a class with a description property and a list of ‘quarter’ classes, and have a list of those.. But I’m not going to write your code for you, sorry.

Comment: Please do not share any code. i just like to know to know how can i deserialize the 
@stuartd pivot data to class<T> ? i can create two class Class1 which will have description property and class2 which will have list of period like List<string> Periods. now my question is without iterate in pivot dataset how can i deserialize the pivot data to class<T> ? any idea would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Why would you want two classes instead of one?

Comment: Personally (depending on requirements) I would look at a `Quarter` class that parses the input "1Q 2019" and stores the year ("2019") and the quarter ("Q1") as appropriate data types. Then you can easily compare quarters across years (i.e. Q1 2018 vs Q1 2019), as well as determine actual vs estimated and year totals, both of which appear in OP's image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Revenue> revenues = new List<Revenue>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
            for (int quarter = 1; quarter <= 4; quarter++)
            {
                for (int year = 2019; year < 2020; year++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(quarter.ToString() + "Q " + year.ToString() + "A",typeof(decimal));
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mainline", 7082.5, 8504, 8552.7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Regional Carriers", 1642.5, 1982, 1928,3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Total Passenger Revenue", 8725, 10.486, 10.481, 9933 });

            for (int col = 1; col < dt.Rows.Count; col++)
            {
                Revenue revenue = new Revenue();
                revenue.quarter = dt.Columns[col].ColumnName;
                revenues.Add(revenue);
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
                {

                    switch (row.Field<string>("Description"))
                    {
                        case "Mainline" :
                            revenue.Mainline = (decimal)row[col];
                            break;
                        case "Regional Carriers":
                            revenue.RegionalCarriers = (decimal)row[col];
                            break;
                        case "Total Passenger Revenue":
                            revenue.TotalPassengerRevenue = (decimal)row[col];
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
 
        }

    }

    public class Revenue
    {
        public string quarter { get; set; }
        public decimal Mainline { get; set; }
        public decimal RegionalCarriers { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPassengerRevenue { get; set; }
    }


}
```

---

Here is a more generic approach using a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Revenue> revenues = new List<Revenue>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
            for (int quarter = 1; quarter <= 4; quarter++)
            {
                for (int year = 2019; year < 2020; year++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(quarter.ToString() + "Q " + year.ToString() + "A",typeof(decimal));
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mainline", 7082.5, 8504, 8552.7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Regional Carriers", 1642.5, 1982, 1928,3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Total Passenger Revenue", 8725, 10.486, 10.481, 9933 });

            for (int col = 1; col < dt.Rows.Count; col++)
            {
                Revenue revenue = new Revenue();
                revenue.quarter = dt.Columns[col].ColumnName;
                revenues.Add(revenue);

                revenue.dict = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { description = x.Field<string>("Description"), amount = (decimal)x[col] })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.description, y => y.amount)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            }
 
        }

    }

    public class Revenue
    {
        public string quarter { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, decimal> dict { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: i have not get the answer from your code. i like to know how could i deserialize my pivot result set to my class. in the above hard coded things. anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: Isn't that what my sample code does?  For testing I created a datatable dt  with test data for four quarters, and then put results into a List<Revenue>.

Comment: I will test your second set of code and let your know. i marked as answer. thanks for your code sample.